# Lorenz system at 13.926

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory

Lorenz system is

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   x' = -\sigma  x + \sigma  y \\
   y' = x \left (r - z \right ) - y \\
   z' = xy - bz
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $\sigma = 10, b = \frac{8}{3}$

I am trying to find out what occurs with the Lorenz system when $r$ changes from $r < 13.926$ to $r >13.926.$ In some literature, it is said that  the attractor of the curve should change: if the curve was attracted to point $\left (\sqrt{b\left(r -1\right )}, \sqrt{b\left(r -1\right )}, r - 1 \right )$ then now it should attract to  $\left (-\sqrt{b\left(r -1\right )}, -\sqrt{b\left(r -1\right )}, r - 1 \right).$ Nevertheless my experiments shows that it is not true. For example, for if start point is $\left(-10, -10, 10\right )$ then the moment of attractor change is between $r=7$ and $r=8.$ So, what actually occurs when $r$ changes from $r < 13.926$ to $r >13.926$

Comment: Your values of $r$ cannot be understood by the layman (as I am) unless you recall what are the equations behind all that, or at least give a reference.

Comment: @JeanMarie added

Comment: Very well. Thanks.

Comment: Avoid using `*` to denote multiplication. This symbol should be reserved for operations like convolution and conjugation. `\cdot` is a better alternative.

Comment: The system is invariant under simultaneous sign change in $x$ and $y$. So these equilibrium points are essentially equivalent. It is unclear what you mean with switching the attracting point. What can change is the stability, that is the structure of the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at these points. Meaning the points can change from fully attracting to attracting in one direction and spiraling outward in some transversal plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that every orbit changes attractor when $r>13.926$. The "change" is mostly noticed around the origin.

These are the (approximate) basins of attraction of the two non trivial equilibrium points for $r=12$, in the section of the plane $\pi:\{(x, y, z):  z=0, |x|<30,|y|<30\}$. The origin is at the center of the picture. Points in red are attracted by one equilibrium and points in blue are attracted by the other. Since the whole Lorenz system is symmetric around the origin, the basins are too.

[image]

And these are the basins in the same section for $r=14$. Note that most points are still attracted to the same equilibrium, but around the origin all points have switched attractor.

[image]